# "Click here if you are not redirected automatically"

Tags: forms, interaction-design, response-time, microinteractions

After the users have filled in a form, they hit submit.
There are a lot of things happening behind the scenes the users won't see, so we send them to a page that says:

> Click here if you are not redirected automatically.

Next to the phrase above there is a button with the label "Back to the form".

I was wondering if there is a way to better phrase the information, and to reframe the action we invite the users to make.

Any better examples? Any advice?

Comment: Could you provide more details? I don't quite understand what the "Back to the form" button is for

Comment: In what cases would the automatic redirection fail? Are you running some code which might lead to an error and the user might not be automatically redirected? What are these lot of things happening behind the scene?

Comment: Please click here if the page does not redirect automatically ...

Answer (score 2):

Create page that shows some message with two buttons: “Back to the form” and “Continue” The second button performs the manual redirection.

Preview:

[image: form preview]

It is also possible to hide the message for some time using CSS animations. Such approach works even with disabled JavaScript.

Comment: What is the difference between back to form and continue?

Comment: *Back to form* moves the user back to the form. *Continue* performs the “redirection”. I expect that the redirection does not point back to the form. If it does, there could be only one button with text like *Ok*.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove "back to form" and also try to solve the need for this type of page altogether by sorting out the issue with the development team. Either way, why would you want the user to go back to a form they just filled?

Comment: User can prevent redirections by configuring the browser. Developer has completely no control over this, so such link is used as fallback solution. When client-side scripting is used used for “redirection” (actually not a redirection, but the script [commands the browser to go to other page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href)), the developer does not know whether the client-side script will execute before it is sent to the browser. (There are causes such as disabled JS, bug in code etc.) The fallback to link is still better than being stuck at blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the user to go back to the form. Instead I would label CTA for Back to Home (if it's an e-commerce website).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a primary CTA, which I believe in your case is the "click to redirect".
The "back to form" seems like a secondary option.

Having the first a link and the second a button is counter intuitive, looks like you're inviting the user, in the default general case, to go back to the form instead of going forward.
Buttons are generally more prominent than links.

That said, the design suggested by [@jiwopene](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/138513/16604) is a step in the right direction.